# Run OAuth URLRequest every hour? - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, oauth, alamofire, access-token

I am using an API in my iOS application that only allows a user to have an OAuth access token for an hour. How would I go about getting a new access token every hour? Would I set a `TimeInterval` or how would I be able to check if the access token is expired?

Here is how I retrieve my access token with `Alamofire`. And I do not need a refresh token as mobile apps do not get them.

```
guard let url = URL(string: "https://www.reddit.com/api/v1/access_token") else { return }
            let uuid = UUID().uuidString
            let params: Parameters = [
                "grant_type" : "https://oauth.reddit.com/grants/installed_client",
                "device_id" : "\(uuid)"]


            let username = "MY_CLIENT_ID"
            let password = ""
            let loginString = String(format: "%@:%@", username, password)
            let loginData = loginString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)! as NSData
            let base64EncodedString = loginData.base64EncodedString()

            let headers = ["Content-Type" : "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
                           "Authorization" : "Basic \(base64EncodedString)"]

            Alamofire.request(url, method: .post , parameters: params, encoding: URLEncoding.httpBody, headers: headers).responseJSON { (response) in

                UserDefaults.standard.set(uuid, forKey: "userID")
                UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
                if let JSON = response.result.value as? [String:Any] {
                    guard let accessToken = JSON["access_token"] as? String else { return }
                    KeychainWrapper.standard.set(accessToken, forKey: "oauthToken")
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way is to check if token is valid when doing api call and authenticate it again if it is about to expire. You can decode token using JWTDecode library. -> [JWTDecode](https://github.com/auth0/JWTDecode.swift)

You can debug print Your token and try to see what informations You get inside using this website https://jwt.io